# Exam structure and final evaluation, corrective factors

Tags: exams, evaluation

I've in front of me a real exam. It has two questions, first one divided in two parts (second part can not be answered without first one correctly answered) rated 3 and 2 points respectively. Second question is divided in three parts, rated 2, 2, and 1. Total, 10 points.

I like to known if there are analysis (could be tables) about how the exam structure impacts on final evaluation and the necessary corrective factors.

Returning to the example, a very **simplistic** analysis: if I assume that the a prior probability of answer correctly a part is 50% (students that must be rated "5"):

First question:

- Fails first part: 50% of students of this class, rated 0
- Correct first part, fails second: 25% of students, rated 3.
- Both parts ok: 25%, rated 5

Second question:

- Fails first part: 50% of students, rated 0
- Correct first part, fails second: 25% of students, rated 2.
- Correct first and second part, fails third: 12.5% of students, rated 4.
- All parts ok: 12.5%, rated 5

Students that have this hypothetical 50% of knowledge will have an average rate of 50%*0+25%*3+25%*5+50%*0+25%*2+12.5%*4+12.5%*5=3.625. It needs a corrective factor of 1.39. Only a 43.75% of these students will pass (rate>5) if no corrective factor is used.

Thus, it seems "mathematically unfair".

Improving analysis after comment of @SolarMike: the average evaluation and factors for other a prior knowledge ratios are:
10% => 0.54, x1.85; 30% => 1.9, x1.59; 50% => 3,6, x1.39; 70% => 5,8 x1.21; 100% => 10, x1.

Comment: So if a student gets all parts correct they score 11.4 out of 10?

Comment: @SolarMike: good comment, probably scale factor is not lineal.

Comment: The assumption that a 50% student will have the same probability of answering each question seems completely unreasonable to me.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: thanks for your interest in this question. Any suggestion or reference about how to improve the analysis ? do you mean that an exam with this structure is fair ?

Comment: To someone who vote for close the question as community-specific/out-of-scope: rationale of your decision ? I supose you do not mean that use a concrete example makes it community-specific.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like in your idealized model, the exam grade is a sum of independent Bernoulli random variables. With this assumption, as a math problem the question is trivial: if you want to achieve a pass rate of X%, the “corrective factor” is any monotone increasing function that maps the grade range of 0-10 to itself and maps the grade of Y to the minimal passing grade of 5, where Y is the X-percentile (in your example, the fiftieth percentile, or median) of the grade distribution.

The problem is that your model is hopelessly unrealistic, and, moreover, a real life class of students is not going to conform to any easy to describe (or even difficult to describe) mathematical model that can be written down in advance. There isn’t a professor on earth who can model their students’ test-taking performance at a level of accuracy that makes it a reasonable idea to determine a corrective factor ahead of time based on a theoretical analysis or (as you suggested in the question) table lookup, since each class of students and the way they will perform on each specific test after sitting in on a specific class are unique.

In practice, you give the exam, look at the actual grade distribution, and, if you believe in grading to a curve or have a reason to aim for a particular pass rate, you set the curve/corrective factor accordingly at that point based on the empirical distribution of grades. That’s about as scientific as it gets, unless maybe we’re talking about a highly standardized test like the SAT with question banks of thousands of questions that get given repeatedly over many years, a “class” of millions of students, and teams of statisticians that can perform large scale analysis to try to uniformize grade distributions across different testing cycles (even then, I think the way they do it is ultimately not too different from the empirical approach I described above; but I could be wrong).